# Reading CSS values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, return-value

I wonder whether there is a way to read a special css-value of a class with jQuery. The scenario looks more or less like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box { margin-top: 100px; }
```

Now I would like to check whether that .box has a margin-top of 100px or not to make in if-statement based on it.

Comment: You can't actually read the value from the `.box` rule, but you can use `.css('margin-top')` to get the element's current computed margin-top value.

Comment: thank you, that's interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is exactly as **Jason** referred in the his comment. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/hWLG5/) for your reference

jquery used:

```
$(function(){
    if($(".box").css('margin-top') == '100px'){
        alert('yes');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah thank you! Also for the fiddle! 

But I still can't get working the thing I want to. I wanted to use this in an if-statement to check if a special action (reducing the margin-top of a special div) is allowed to be fired. My problem is: 

I have a prev/next navigation and when there is no "prev" or "next" element, the margin-top has to be animated to 0. Everything works fine, but when you double-click when this action has to take place the margin-top value gets two times the negative value...

Have a look at it on line 62 following: http://jsfiddle.net/mleyendecker/632Fw/156/

Comment: @MarcL good.. i have also created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/39james/eCUR9/. If you want you can take a look at this. Basically what i did is when the navigation reaches the last item, i make it `visible:hidden`. My styles are not correct, so check the JQuery section and try adding it to your fiddle.